# Erasing a point in QField

Tags: qfield

Maybe it is a very simple question but i couldn't find it anywhere.

I'd like to erase a point feature using QField. If I draw any feature the garbage icon appears but this is not possible by selecting a point (or any other feature) Is it possible? How?

Comment: Which qfield version are you using?

Comment: And can you be more precise what you mean with "but this is not possible by selecting a point (or any other feature)"

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answer. The version is 1.0.0-rc3. I have three point layers (geopackage) representing survey landmarks. If the mark is destroyed i'd like erase the point from my layer. So. I select the layer, change to edition mode, select the point...and? I can read the fields associated to it, i can edit the fields, i can add points to the layer, but i don't know how to erase the point...if it is possible.Thank you very much!!

Comment: I've found out the problem was that i was storing my project data in the memory card of my mobile phone. When I've moved it to the internal memory the trash icon has appeared.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible.

Make sure you prepare Qfield project right for mobile device. First check your layer is not read only in Project properties then configure project in QFieldSync plugin:

[image: Destop project properties]

[image: Plugin project configuration]

Package project with plugin:

[image: Package project]

This should produce _qfield.qgs and data.gpkg files that you need to copy on mobile device, both in same folder.

When you select feature in digitizing mode, as needed for drawing, there should be trash symbol next to it in attribute tabel:

[image: delete feature]

I tried using QField data directly from Drive but that does not work, you need to download all the files and open project from the folder that is stored on the device.

Qgis version: 3.4, Qfield v.: 1.0.-rc3

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answer. The version is 1.0.0-rc3. I have three point layers (geopackage) representing survey landmarks. If the mark is destroyed i'd like erase the point from my layer. So. I select the layer, change to edition mode, select the point...and? I can read the fields associated to it, i can edit the fields, i can add points to the layer, but i don't know how to erase the point...if it is possible.Thank you very much!!

Comment: There should be trash icon next to feature in the attribute table after you select it in digitizing mode. If you can add and edit features in layer than it is possible to delete. You can delete features of this layer in desktop project?

Comment: Hello! I've checked the QGIS project in desktop and i can erase points there normally. There's no trash icon when i select a point. BUT. A message "No feature at this position" appears when i select the point. Then i see a identification number of the point, and when i select that number i can see all the fields...any idea?? The layers are in geopackage format, could be it?? Thank you for your interest!!

Comment: Ok, when you package layers for qfield, you set point layers for offline editing and you got 2 files to transfer to mobile device: _qfield.qgis and data.gpkg? You have both of this files in same folder on device? If so, data should be ok. When you see all the fields, ate there arrows on top of the table for left and right? if you use one of these, you should get to the "trash option". Else is it possible you have wrong layer selected? Also, you could try making new project with some random points and see if there woroks..

Comment: Hello! Here i come back again... You say "...set the points layers for offline editing.." I think that's the point. How can i do that? In QGIS Desktop, in Project Properties, in Display I select Identifiable and NOT SELECT Read Only. Is it? The files i have in the mobile phone are QRTM_qfield.qgd, QRTM_qfield.qgs, QRTM_qfield.qgs~, RTM5XXX.gpkg, RTM6XXX.gpkg and RTM9XXX.gpkg all in the same folder.

Comment: When i select the point, and select the identification number and i can see the field, if i touch the arrows just close the menu that shows the field editing button and draw entity button...there is no trash button. I have done a new project with three sample points and i get the same....Thank you very much!!

Comment: In desktop go to plugins,  qfieldsync, project configuration there you can set layer for offline editing. Was this the missing puzzle?

Comment: Hello! In QGIS Desktop, in Complements, in ActiveSync i configure the layers for ''offline edition", and then i export the project with QField ActiveSync to the mobile phone. When i open the project QField tells me that the layers couldn't be loaded and show a list with the name of the layer and the source of data "dbname='./data.sqlite'table="RTMXXX..." It doesn't looks get better... Thank you for your concern...I'm sorry be so disturbing

Comment: I edited answer, if you follow this and it does not work i can not help unless you provide some of your data to testi it..

Comment: So do I. As i tell you in the answer i'll send you any data you need. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your data is good, i can delete points from your project. I updated answer.. You sure you are loading project from device, from folder where you downloaded it to? If you are doing all like in my answer i cant help anymore. You could try still on some other mobile device to see if its you or your device :) But data is definitly good.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update for someone having the same problem in March 2021: As with QField 1.8.4 i found out that you actually have to LONG-press the feature, as there is no trash-symbol like shown in the upper solution. There you can access a Trash-Symbol.